# Accessing ActiveRecord virtual attributes programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this partial that's supposed to generate a block of code I'm repeating a lot through a page.

The main view has something like this:

**index.html.haml**

```
=render 'dropdownboxes', name: 'Locations', association: @locations, option: 'name', option_id: 'id', query: 'location'
```

And the partial contains something similar to this (haml):

**_dropdownboxes.html.haml**

```
.btn-group
  %button.btn-u.btn-u-sm.btn-u-dark.dropdown-toggle{'data-toggle' => 'dropdown'}
    =name
    %i.fa.fa-angle-down
  %ul.dropdown-menu{:role => 'menu'}
    - association.each do |c|
     %li=link_to c[option], params.merge({query => c[option_id]})
```

*Before you freak out, I'm splitting the parameters so the queries are not vulnerable to XSS attacks in the controller.*

The last line would generate a link similar to this:

```
<a href="/search/?state=1">California</a>
```

This works perfectly for certain cases, however, when I use a virtual attribute on the Model, the generated link does not work as expected; specifically, the 'option' value is nil.

The Model has two fields, "city" and "state". In the Model, I have this virtual attribute defined as:

**location.rb**

```
def place
  [city, state].join(', ')
end
```

From the console:

```
> test=Location.all.first
> test.id            # => 1
> test.['id']        # => 1
> test.city          # => "Los Angeles"
> test['city']       # => "Los Angeles"
> test.state         # => "California"
> test['state']      # => "California"
> test.place         # => "Los Angeles, California"
> test['place']      # => nil
```

So the virtual attribute appears as nil, which I assume it's cause it's not being parsed into the array. When I try to send this to html with the partial render, it prints something like this:

```
<a href="/search/?location=1">/search/?location=1</a>
```

I'm trying to access it this way, cause I'm using `c[option]` in the partial described above, which retrieves the value. Is there a better way to access the virtual value without switching to an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a Ruby method by name using `send`:

```
c.send('place')
```

This works for both plain Ruby methods (i.e., your "virtual attribute") and ActiveRecord attributes, whereas `c['place']` only works for the latter.

Comment: Short and concise. Perfect!